# Tag Removal Request: "School"

Tags: discussion

There are [8 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/school) tagged with "school". Is this really needed or can it be burnificated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first thought was that there should be no need for it. After a bit more consideration I think it should stay.

School environments tend to be quite different to "normal" commercial environments or data centers. If I see a question tagged `school` I immediately have sympathy for the poster and will definitely read the question differently than I would if it was about something such as an office environment.

If we get rid of the `school` tag, should the `datacenter` tag also be eliminated for the same reasons?

Comment: I agree that `school` may be valid, but I was just reviewing the questions with that tag.  At least half of them are junk and probably should be closed & deleted.

Comment: @Zoredache, perhaps get rid of the questions and leave the tag to be used when it is appropriate.